# PYTHON lex and yacc

Tags: python, ply

```
import ply.lex as lex
tokens=("NAME","REST")
t_REST='.'

def t_NAME(t) :
    r'\#define\s+(\w+)\s+(.+)'
    print(t.lexer.lexmatch.groups())

def t_error(t):
    print("ERROR")

lexer=lex.lex()
lexer.input('#define RAD 100')
for t in lexer:
    pass
```

Output of this program is -

```
('#define RAD 100', 'RAD', '100', None)
```

Can anyone explain how `t.lexer.lexmatch.groups()` works?

Comment: Why the output which is tuple has 'None' as one of its value?

Comment: Check what `t.lexer.lexmatch.re.pattern` is.

Comment: Can you explain?I didnt understand

Comment: You are wondering about the None in the regex match results. It means an optional group in the pattern did not match. So, try to get to the pattern to understand.